# Query Syntax Working Fine in PhpMyAdmin but Not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert

So I have this query

```
$searchresult = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytemp
                    (
                    id INT(11) UNSIGNED,
                    stationname varchar(30),
                    stationprice float,
                    image text,
                    updated date,
                    created text,
                    paid tinyint(1),
                    url text
                    );
                    INSERT into mytemp (id, stationname, stationprice, image, updated, created, paid, url) 

                    SELECT  id, stationname1 AS stationname,stationprice1 AS stationprice,image1 AS image, updated1 AS updated, created1 AS created, active1 AS paid, url1 AS url
                    FROM fuel 
                    WHERE (stationname1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                    UNION
                    SELECT  id, stationname2 AS stationname,  stationprice2 AS stationprice, image2 AS image, updated2 AS updated, created2 AS created, active2 AS paid, url2 AS url
                    FROM fuel 
                    WHERE (stationname2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                    UNION
                    SELECT  id, stationname3 AS stationname,  stationprice3 AS stationprice,image3 AS image, updated3 AS updated, created3 AS created, active3 AS paid, url3 AS url
                    FROM fuel 
                    WHERE (stationname3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                    UNION
                    SELECT  id, stationname4 AS stationname, stationprice4 AS stationprice, image4 AS image, updated4 AS updated, created4 AS created, active4 AS paid, url4 AS url
                    FROM fuel 
                    WHERE (stationname4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%'); 

                    SELECT mytemp.id, mytemp.stationname, mytemp.stationprice, mytemp.image, mytemp.updated, mytemp.created, mytemp.paid, themes.rating, themes.url
                    FROM mytemp
                    INNER JOIN themes ON mytemp.url=themes.url
                    ORDER BY $searchvar;";
```

Which gives me an error message ==> 
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT into mytemp (id, stationname, stationprice, image, updated, created, paid' at line 12".

When I feed it into phpmyadmin like:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytemp
(
id INT(11) UNSIGNED,
stationname varchar(30),
stationprice float,
image text,
updated date,
created text,
paid tinyint(1),
url text
);
INSERT into mytemp

SELECT  id, stationname1 AS stationname, stationprice1 AS stationprice,image1 AS image, updated1 AS updated, created1 AS created, active1 AS paid, url1 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname1 LIKE '%wwo%' OR stationinfo1 LIKE '%wwo%' OR url1 LIKE '%wwo%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname2 AS stationname, stationprice2 AS stationprice, image2 AS image, updated2 AS updated, created2 AS created, active2 AS paid, url2 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname2 LIKE '%wwo%' OR stationinfo2 LIKE '%wwo%' OR url2 LIKE '%wwo%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname3 AS stationname, stationprice3 AS stationprice,image3 AS image, updated3 AS updated, created3 AS created, active3 AS paid, url3 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname3 LIKE '%wwo%' OR stationinfo3 LIKE '%wwo%' OR url3 LIKE '%wwo%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname4 AS stationname, stationprice4 AS stationprice, image4 AS image, updated4 AS updated, created4 AS created, active4 AS paid, url4 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname4 LIKE '%wwo%' OR stationinfo4 LIKE '%wwo%' OR url4 LIKE '%wwo%');

SELECT mytemp.id, mytemp.stationname, mytemp.stationprice, mytemp.image, mytemp.updated, mytemp.created, mytemp.paid, themes.rating, themes.url
FROM mytemp
INNER JOIN themes ON mytemp.url=themes.url
ORDER BY rating;
```

it works like a charm. I can't figure out the problem. So far I have tried putting variables in quotes and using alias tables but nothing seems to work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show how you are executing the query?

Comment: Try to split the query into three php queries: create, insert, select. If that works you can probably tweak your MySQL configuration to allow multiple statements per query.

Comment: @Ivar I execute it like so "$result = mysqli_query($con,$searchresult);   
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}"

Comment: @KosyOnyenso Give this a read: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: @jh1711 separating it solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using multiple query statements within the same string. 
I currently solved it by separating the statements like

```
$searchresult = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytemp
                        (
                        id INT(11) UNSIGNED,
                        stationname varchar(30),
                        stationprice float,
                        image text,
                        updated date,
                        created text,
                        paid tinyint(1),
                        url text
                        );";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$searchresult); 

                    $searchresult = "INSERT into mytemp (id, stationname, stationprice, image, updated, created, paid, url) 

                        SELECT  id, stationname1 AS stationname,stationprice1 AS stationprice,image1 AS image, updated1 AS updated, created1 AS created, active1 AS paid, url1 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url1 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname2 AS stationname,  stationprice2 AS stationprice, image2 AS image, updated2 AS updated, created2 AS created, active2 AS paid, url2 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url2 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname3 AS stationname,  stationprice3 AS stationprice,image3 AS image, updated3 AS updated, created3 AS created, active3 AS paid, url3 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url3 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT  id, stationname4 AS stationname, stationprice4 AS stationprice, image4 AS image, updated4 AS updated, created4 AS created, active4 AS paid, url4 AS url
                        FROM fuel 
                        WHERE (stationname4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR stationinfo4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%' OR url4 LIKE '%" . $type .  "%');";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$searchresult);

                        $searchresult = "SELECT mytemp.id, mytemp.stationname, mytemp.stationprice, mytemp.image, mytemp.updated, mytemp.created, mytemp.paid, themes.rating, themes.url
                        FROM mytemp
                        INNER JOIN themes ON mytemp.url=themes.url
                        ORDER BY $searchvar $choice;";
```

based on [jh1711](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7401610/jh1711) 's reply.
[Ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479156/ivar) also brought up the point of using mysqli_multi_query() as per this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php .
Thanks guys!!.